# Can't connect to cumulocity using trial account

Tags: cumulocity

I've added 2 accounts to MQTTBox, one is a trial account the other is not.
With the trial account i fail to connect to cumulocity.

Here's my config:

[MQTTBox config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHOiT.png)

I've also tried setting Username as nur.eu-latest/nuno.rodrigues@together.pt

Why can't i connect with the trial account? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prefix in your domain (nur) is not necessarily the ID of your tenant (that depends on the Cumulocity installation and the way your tenant was generated).

MQTT always requires the actual ID of the tenant.

You can for example use postman to check the actual ID of your tenant:

```
GET /tenant/currentTenant HTTP/1.1
Host: nur.eu-latest-cumulocity.com
Authorization: {{auth}}
```

The result should look something like this

```
{
    "allowCreateTenants": false,
    "customProperties": {},
    "domainName": "nur.eu-latest-cumulocity.com",
    "name": "t1234567890",
    "applications": "..."
}
```

The "name" is what you need to use.